# Is it wrong when you use "might + inf" when you are telling a past story?

Tags: word-usage, modality

See this conversation:

> A: There was robbery here. What happened?
>
> B: I saw a man yesterday. He went to the house. He **might enter** the
>   house but I am not sure.

is it wrong to use "**might enter**" in the above context?

In the above context, do we have to change "**might enter**" to "**might have entered**"?

I would say "**might enter**" means "it was possible that he entered", say it was the future at that time in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You would only answer “might enter” if you thought he was still standing outside the house and he still might go in. Yesterday seems like too long ago for that to make sense, so “might have entered” is the better choice.

> I saw a man yesterday. He went to the house. He might have entered the house but I am not sure.

On the other hand, if we change the timeframe, we can use “might enter”:

> I saw a man run past here two minutes ago. He went over to that house. I think he’s hiding in those bushes. He might enter the house but I am not sure.

Comment: So, "**might enter**" in the above context talks about future. But what about the one in indirect speech: He said "I may enter"=He said that he might enter. "He might enter" in the indirect speech is about the past?

Comment: In the case of: _He said that he might enter_, the only thing that is in the past is (the time of) his utterance; it's no different than: _He said that he likes cheeseburgers,_ or: _He said that the Nigerian flag is green and white_, or: _He said that he will go to the dentist next week_.

Comment: What about "Conditional Type 2", "if he had a tool, he might enter" ("might" here is the simple past of "may")

Comment: @Tom - Where are you getting this notion that "might" is the past tense of "may"? That's an outdated notion! (You can read more [here on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/are-might-and-should-past-tenses-of-may-and-shall-respectively) and [here in Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/usage/may-or-might).) The way to say it is: "If he had had a tool, he might have entered."

Comment: Cambridge grammar says: ‘I may be back later,’ she said=She said she might be back later. (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech) How can you explain it?

Comment: How did you get from _‘I may be back later,’ she said_ = _She said she might be back later_ all the way to _He might enter the house but I am not sure_? With “she said she might be back later,” she controls her own actions. A parallel might be “he said he might go into the house.”

Comment: and "might" in “he said he might go into the house.” is the past form of "may".

Answer (score 1):

You need "might have entered" here.

"Might", like most modals, has two distinct meanings, one *deontic* (about possibilities and potentialities) and one *epistemic* (about knowledge of possibilities).

In some contexts, both meanings are possible, and phrases may actually be ambiguous.

But in a statement (as opposed to a question) the modal ("might" or "could") followed by a plain ("present") infinitive can only have a deontic meaning:
"he might enter" is about his intentions and "he could enter" is about his potentiality.

Since the meaning you want here is epistemic (you're not talking about the possibility of his entering the house, but about your lack of knowledge) you have to use the past infinitive "have entered".

This is parallel with the use of past forms for irrealis conditionals (sometimes called the "third conditional"): "If he had entered" as opposed to "If he entered", which is a realis conditional. 
Generally, if you use

Comment: What about "might" in reported speech & 2nd conditional?

He said "I may enter"= He said he might enter; If he had a tool, he might enter (2nd cond)